# USB Driver App Not start: Termination Reason: Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x1

Tags: macos, usb, provisioning-profile, code-signing-entitlements, driverkit

I'm developing the following files.

- driver.dext: User-mode USB driver
- Driver.app: Application to install the
  user-mode USB driver

I created new App IDs and provisioning profiles for the executable files. And I added the keys and values of the entitlements.

I set the certificates, provisioning profiles and entitlement files in Xcode. The build in Xcode succeeded and the notarization also succeeded by command. But I can not run the Driver.app. The crash log says the following message.

Termination Reason: Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x01

I tried security command and the output shows that the Provisioning Profile contains the following.

- dext: "driverkit.transport.usb" and "driverkit"
- App: "driverkit.userclient-access" ,"system-extension.install", "system-extension.uninstall"

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: I think you need to disable sip

Comment: I tried to disable sip, but the same error occurs.